# Can the singleton contract be broken? If yes in how many ways?

Tags: java, singleton, synchronized, volatile, cloning

Recently I appeared for the interview and she/he asked me the question  - you have below singleton class and you have to break the singleton contract, tell me how to do that? I thought and thought about the ways but I couldn't come up to the solutions as every check was there to prevent the violation like -

1. Volatile keyword to read/write from the main memory
2. Synchronized around the method and block
3. Static method to get the instance
4. Double checking if instance is available or not
5. Private constructor

Below is the code -

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.test.singleton;

/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class SingletonInstance implements Cloneable{

    private String name;

    private static volatile SingletonInstance instance;

     private SingletonInstance(){

        System.out.println("constructor called");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    static synchronized SingletonInstance getInstance(){

    if(instance == null){

        synchronized(SingletonInstance.class){
            instance = new SingletonInstance();
        }

    }
    return instance;
}

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#clone()
     */
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

Please suggest if it's possible to break the singleton contract in any way?

Comment: You didn't specify what "break the contract" means specifically.  Regardless, this code is incorrect, it will ALWAYS throw NPE when `getInstance()` is called (the effectively `synchronized(null)`) so it will never initialize the instance.

Comment: You tried cloning and it returned the same instance? I don't believe you.

Comment: Thanks, Jim for pointing that out. Corrected the code. And from the term "break the contract" I meant in any way can the two instances of the class be created and this has been already answered by @Ernest in very good way using reflection and also how to prevent that

Comment: @shmosel From the term same instance, I was thinking of the same content of the instance at the time writing the question. Now I realized wording was incorrect. Did the correction in the question. Thanks !!!

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use cloning to solve this.

Comment: @shmosel I think you are not getting the question .. I want to create the fresh new instance and the cloning will create just the copy of the existing instance.

Comment: You asked how to "break the singleton contract". Having multiple instances, whether "fresh" or not, already breaks the definition of a singleton.

Comment: @shmosel Got the point. Once I get the instance from cloning I can play around with this independent of other instances....And Yes... cloning is also breaking the singleton contract... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are several situations your Singleton Class may have multiple instances. As of now, I have 2 points in my mind.

1. Invoking private constructor trough reflection.
2. Through Serialization and Deserialization.

Here is the way to stop creating an object through private constructor invocation.

```
private SingletonInstance(){
          if(instance != null){
                throw new OperationNotSupportedException("You can't create object of singletone class using this operation");
         }
       }
```

Also, you can stop creating multiple objects of singleton class through serialization and deserialization by adding readObject and readResolve method like below.

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream inputStream) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException  {
    inputStream.defaultReadObject();
    instance = this;
}

private Object readResolve() {
    return instance;
}
```

Also, your clone method should through an exception.

```
  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
       throw new CloneNotSupportedException("Clone not supported for this class");
    }
```

Comment: reflection can still defeat your private constructor if invoked from a separate thread. you need to synchronize the test for null to force the effectiveness of `volatile`

Comment: you have a type `throw an exception`

Comment: You cannot use Serialization here, as `SingletonInstance` does not implement `Serializable` and its `private` constructor effectively prevents serializable subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor, although private, can be invoked using reflection:

```
Class<SingletonInstance> klass = SingletonInstance.class;
Constructor<SingletonInstance> defaultConstructor = klass.getConstructor();

defaultConstructor.setAccessible(true);
SingletonInstance newInstance = defaultConstructor.newInstance();
```

With that, multiple instances can be created.

To prevent that, it should contain its own check, as suggested in effective java:

```
private SingletonInstance(){ 
    if(instance != null)
        throw new IllegalStateException(); //or some other exception
    System.out.println("constructor called"); 
}
```

Comment: reflection can still defeat your private constructor if invoked from a separate thread. you need to synchronize the test for null to force the effectiveness of `volatile`

Comment: @Bohemian even `synchronized` doesn’t help here, as you can simply create you own instance before the first call to `getInstance()` without any concurrency involved.